# iPhone NSURL get last redirected url

Tags: iphone, url, redirect

i wonder how can you update your NSURL to the last url that a your url will redirect to
using NSURL or NSRequest

appreciate your help.
thanks.

Answer (score 8):

zanque's solution works, but in order to avoid downloading "useless" data, I'd change the http method to HEAD :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:orinigalURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSURL *finalURL = response.URL;
```

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment instead of an answer. Or perhaps an edit.

Comment: @EWit, the user has 1 Rep. They can't post a comment. Additionally, this provides an alternative answer to the question.

Comment: @Andy I just made a comment meant to provide some, future, guidance. But because it extends on an existing answer it might have been better put it as an edit on the answer so people reading it are made aware of both the issue and the solution. Also there is a reason I chose to use "might be" instead of "should be".

Answer (score 6):

i did it,

here is how

```
NSURL *originalUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YourURL.com"];
NSData *data=nil;  
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:originalUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSURL *LastURL=[response URL];
[request release];
[error release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll only be able to find this out after trying to connect using NSURLConnection. If you add a method to your NSURLConnection delegate, -connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:, you'll be notified before redirects happen. Just grab the URL from the passed request, and that's your answer.

Comment: I don't believe so. Apple discourages synchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

You cause following swift code to get the final redirected url:

```
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        var response: URLResponse? = nil
        do {
            try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: &response)
        } catch { //Handle exception //if any
        }
        let finalURL = response?.url
```